# can't get setState inside a firebase function out of it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

first i set `listaa` as a global variable
i'm trying to take out the  variable(array) "listaa" from the firebase function that sets it... I'm plannig to use it later to make some maths.
I used `console.log(listaa)` inside the firebase function and it worked,
but then when i try to use it() outside(the firebase function) it doens't work.
I tried to use setState to make it usable outside but didnt work too

```
if (funcionar == 0) {
        //============================================================== ANTES ===================================================
        var newRef = firebase
          .database()
          .ref()
          .child("TransferenciasPraVendedores/")
          .push({
            vendedor: vend,
            dia: functions.dataHoje(),
            hora: functions.horaHoje()
          });


        var fire = database.ref("EstoqueCadaVendedor/" + vend);
        fire.once("value", snap => {
          items = [];
          snap.forEach(data => {
            items.push({
              key: data.key,
              data: data.val()
            });
          });
          console.log("items:");
          console.log(items);

          for (j = 0; j < prod.length; j++) {
            // var a = parseInt(snap.val().quantidade);
            console.log("d: " + items[j].data);
            listaa.push(items[j].data);
          }
          // this.setState({ lista:listaa })
          // console.log("lista:");
          // console.log(this.state.lista[2]);
          console.log("listaa");
          console.log(listaa);
        });
        console.log("listaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        console.log(listaa);
```

Ill use 'listaa' here:

```
        for (i = 0; i < prod.length; i++) {
          firebase
            .database()
            .ref()
            .child("EstoqueCadaVendedor/" + vend + "/")
            .update({
              [prod[i].key]: parseInt(quantNova[i]) + listaa[i]
            });
        }

        // this.setState({ quantidade: [], vendedor: "" });
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you review the order of the log messages ? if you look carefully, you will recognize the data gets available after later in the process. You probably need to use async/promise to wait until the data gets available or you can use a call back function

> async

function to make sure the data is available in the list before you use it.

> An async function can contain an await expression, that pauses the
>   execution of the function and waits for the passed Promise's
>   resolution, and then resumes the async function's execution and
>   returns the resolved value.

In the example below, I am passing a call back function that gets called when data is available :

```
  export function listReleases(callback) {
  //console.log("hello from list releases ");
  releasesRef.once("value").then(
    function(snapshot) {
      const releases = snapshot.val();
      if (releases) {
        callback("releases", releases);
      }
    },
    function(error) {
      // The Promise was rejected.
      console.error(error);
    }
  );
}

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++


 //call the function to get the data and pass a call back function 
 releases = listReleases(this.myCallback);


 myCallback = (key, value) => {
   //do whatever you need to do in here 
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Tuan over here.

- The reason why you don't see it is because your code is asynchronous, so when you print console.log() at the end. The firebase calls haven't finished yet.This is a typical race condition scenario.
- FYI, I personally prefer to use the promise style rathen than the callback, I think it makes the code cleaner and easier to read. Try this:

  let firebaseDB = firebase.database();

  if (funcionar == 0) {

  ```
  return firebaseDB.ref("TransferenciasPraVendedores/")
    .push({
      vendedor: vend,
      dia: functions.dataHoje(),
      hora: functions.horaHoje()
    })
    .then(() => {
      return firebaseDB.ref("EstoqueCadaVendedor/" + vend).once('value');
    .then(snapshot => {
      let snap = snapshot.val();
      items = [];
      snap.forEach(data => {
        items.push({
          key: data.key,
          data: data.val()
        });
      });

      return {snap, items};
    })
    .then({snap, items} => {
      for (j = 0; j < prod.length; j++) {
        listaa.push(items[j].data);
      }
      //console.log(lista)// NOW your lista should have all the items
      // I would dispatch your redux action here.
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw error
    }
  ```

Let me know if it helped. I can look into it more in depth. Saludos :)